# Split Data where no obvious consistent delimiter: Excel - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to split my Excel data into various columns. The data I have a acquired is inconsistent, in terms of a delimiter, but there are certain attributes to the data that would help separate them into columns. The problem is, I have limited knowledge in Excel and VBA. Below is a sample from the column I want to split into several columns.

[image]

As you can see from the picture above, just using a simple script, which splits the data by a single delimiter, won't work because the addresses can be in a building, a unit or just a single property. However, I did notice that the Suburbs, States and Country are all uppercase. This means there is something I can work with.

So far, all my code does is split the active cell into several cells using a comma delimiter.

```
Sub SplitColoumn()

    Dim rng As range
    s = Split(ActiveCell, ",")

    Set rng = ActiveCell
    rng.Select

    Set rng = rng.Resize(1, 1 + UBound(s) + 1)
    rng.Select

    rng = s

End Sub
```

The results are as expected, because all this code will do is split up the active cell, but I can't seem to figure out how to use a loop and have more control of the constraints.

I want to split the addresses into separate columns for Street, Suburb, State and Postcode.

Thanks

EDIT: I have now added the image, I'm not sure why it didn't appear the first time.

Comment: `As you can see form the picture above[...]` Is it just me or there really no picture attached to see what you mean? Anyway, it would be best if you could paste some sample data into your post (as text) and not as a picture: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557

Comment: No picture for me as well.

Comment: I see nothing but the bracketed box. I checked the edits, and it is wrong there too.

Comment: You'll need IF, Mid and Ucase, Google about for how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to split the addresses into separate columns for Street,
>   Suburb, State and Postcode

I assume you meant separate columns for Street, city, county, country and postcode?

Set a reference to Microsoft VBScript RegularExpression 5.5.
Adjust the following code (Range):

```
Dim rex As RegExp
Dim m As Match, mc As MatchCollection
Dim ran As Range, cel As Range

Set rex = New RegExp
rex.Pattern = "([\w\d\s\,]+?)\,([A-Z\s]+?)\,([A-Z\s]+?)\,([A-Z\s]+?)\,([\d\s]+?)$"

Set ran = Range("A1:A3")

For Each cel In ran
    Set mc = rex.Execute(CStr(cel.Value))
    Set m = mc.Item(0)
    cel = m.SubMatches(0)
    cel.Offset(0, 1) = m.SubMatches(1)
    cel.Offset(0, 2) = m.SubMatches(2)
    cel.Offset(0, 3) = m.SubMatches(3)
    cel.Offset(0, 4) = m.SubMatches(4)
Next cel
```

This will split the contents of each cell into columns.

Comment: Incredible, I had some code to do this and it was about 5 times longer and it also involved me using a second script. I was no where close to getting it right. You did this so eloquently, thank you.

Comment: Also dont forget to enable regular expressions. This can be done under Tools -> References